Hecke operators are multiplicative on Jacobian
I am a total beginner in this field (complex analytic geometry?), so apologies if the question is obvious. Not sure if the context is relevant, but I am studying the Eichler-Shimura construction for elliptic curves attached to weight-$2$ eigenforms. (Question 0: Is my understanding correct that eigenforms of all $T_n$ are sufficient, and not just newforms?)
I know that Hecke operators $T_n$ are multiplicative on modular forms, so $T_{mn} = T_mT_n$ for $(m, n) = 1$ (that's why coefficients of newforms are multiplicative.) I also recently learned that $T_p$ acts on $\mathrm{Jac}(X_0(N))$, because (when $p \nmid N$) it can be thought of as the multi-valued map (correspondence) $T_p: X_0(N) \leftarrow X_0(pN) \stackrel{\mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{H}, z \mapsto pz}{\longrightarrow} X_0(N)$ which induces a map in $T_p \in \mathrm{End}(\mathrm{Jac}(X_0(N)))$. The two definitions agree when viewing weight $2$ cusp forms $f \in \mathcal{S}_2(\Gamma_0(N))$ as a holomorphic $1$-form in $H^0(X_0(N), \Omega^1)$.
Two questions: (1) Is my understanding correct, and (2) what does the identity $T_{mn} = T_mT_n$ "encode" to in this language? $\mathrm{Jac}$ is an abelian group but not multiplicative, and I am not sure if it's just $T_{mn}(D) = T_m(D) + T_m(D)$ for $D \in \mathrm{Jac}(X_0(N))$.
P.S. I thought these techniques / this subfield would be called analytic geometry, just like one of the "GA" in "GAGA", but googling that gives very different things...

(0) Sufficient for what?
(1) I believe your understanding is correct. Note that to write this correspondence, it is important that $p$ be a prime not dividing $N$.
(2) When $n$ is not a prime, a definition of $T_n$ as a correspondence is harder to describe. The easiest way is therefore to view $T_{nm}=T_nT_m$ as a definition: namely, the recurrence relation describes $T_q$ when $q$ is a power of a prime not dividing $N$, then you get all integers coprime to $N$ by stating $T_{nm}=T_nT_m$.
For this to be well-defined, you need to prove that for any primes $p,q$, $T_pT_q=T_qT_p$.
Anyway, the equality $T_{nm}=T_nT_m$ means formally that for any degree-zero divisor $D$ on $X_0(N)$, the difference $T_{nm}(D)-T_n(T_m(D))$ is a principal divisor.
